# Is the pullback bundle of E homomorphic to E?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

> **Proposition 1.5.** Given a map $f\colon A\to B$ and a vector bundle $p\colon E\to B$, then there exists a vector bundle $p′\colon E′\to A$ with a map $f′\colon E′\to E$ taking the fiber of $E′$ over each point $a\in A$ isomorphically onto the fiber of $E$ over $f(a)$, and such a vector bundle $E′$ is unique up to isomorphism
>
> Often the vector bundle $E′$ is written as $f^∗(E)$ and called the bundle *induced* by $f$, or the *pullback* of $E$ by $f$.
>
> (Vector Bundles and K-Theory, Allen Hatcher)

Is $f′$ a vector bundle homomorphism from $f^∗(E)$ to $E$?

Comment: Sure. $f'$ is a vector bundle morphism satisfying $f\circ p'=p\circ f'$ and for every $a\in A$, the map $p'^{-1}(a)\to p^{-1}(f(a))$ induced by $f'$ is an isomorphism between vector spaces.